# Unable to add ICON on the top bar using PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

Issue: 
I have started learning PyGame and trying to add an icon(32x32) image in pygame window beside the title.

Program Here:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))\
pygame.display.set_caption("Rocco's Place")
icon = pygame.image.load("cat.png")
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

run = True
while run:
    win.fill((255,50,100))
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Your code seems to work on Windows 10. Maybe this: the docs say "Some systems do not allow the window icon to change after it has been shown. This function can be called before pygame.display.set_mode() to create the icon before the display mode is set."

Comment: It works under Linux (Ubuntu 19.10) , but the icon appears in the `Alt-Tab` list, not on the menu bar.

Comment: Can you try to set it before pygame.display.set_mode() ? And whats the resulution of the icon? Can you try convert it to 32 x 32 ?

Comment: Yes the Image resolution is 32x32, I am using CentOS.